# Modify date without modifying time

Tags: java, jodatime

With `JodaTime`, without using the 'plus' or 'minus' functions and using the least lines of code, how can I set a new date without modifying the time?

My first attempt was to store the 'time' parts of the `DateTime` in separate `int`s using `getHoursOfDay()` and `getMinutesOfHour()` etc - then create a new `DateTime` with the required date and set the hours, minutes, and seconds back again. But this method is pretty clunky, and I was wondering if there was a less verbose method for doing this - ideally with just one line of code.

For example:

`22/05/2013 13:40:02` >>>> `30/08/2014 13:40:02`

Comment: I've voted to close as primarily opinion-based. The "easiest" route to solving a problem is subjective. If instead you meant "*I don't know how to just change the day/month/year can you show me?*", then edit your question to make that clear. In that case, please also include your best effort.

Comment: `Easiest` changed to `Simplest`, which is far less subjective

Comment: To clarify, I know a couple of ways of doing this already, but they are verbose and clunky. I am looking to see if anyone has a really stream-lined approach available.

Comment: 'Simplest' isn't any better. If you have tried several ways, then show us and point out the awkward parts and ask how the task can be accomplished without those awkward parts.

Comment: @NathanielFord I could change it to `using the least lines of code`? I think this is a pedantic reason to close the question.

Comment: You are asking for an opinion whichever of those ways you put it. Please note that you're failing the actual test of a good question; showing that you put legwork in, have some understanding of whats going on but need help over a particular hurdle. Here you are simply asking an open-ended question and asking others to write your code for you. This is why the question was put on hold. (Note: saying you know a couple of ways but not bothering to show them does not count.)

Comment: @NathanielFord It's arguable that most questions on this site warrant some sort of opinion in some form or another. Regardless, I have improved my question. It's strange, I see lots of other questions that make even less of an attempt to fit the 'good question criteria', but get hundreds of up-votes simply because the question is a common problem. If the criteria for good questions is not entirely maintained and enforced across the whole site then it sets very bad examples for others.

Comment: You can bring your concerns to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ but I will guarantee they've been addressed already. If a question is bad, you should vote to close or flag as appropriate; I assure you there are many questions that have high popularity which are still closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
DateTime myDate = ...
myDate.withDate(desiredYear, desiredMonth, desiredDayOfMonth);
```

JavaDoc is here: [DateTime.withDate(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withDate%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 2):

Is JodaTime a must? Basic way to do this is 
1. extract just time from timestamp.
2. add this to just date

```
long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis(); //OK we have some timestamp
long justTime = timestamp % 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;// just tiem contains just time part


long newTimestamp = getDateFromSomeSource();//now we have date from some source
justNewDate = newTimestamp - (newTimestamp % 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);//extract just date

result = justNewDate + justTime;
```

Something like this.

Comment: My previous attempts at solving this were just as verbose as your suggestion, however you solved the problem using a completely unexpected method, so +1 for that :)

Comment: This doesn't take daylight savings into account.

Answer (score 1):

use [withFields](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/src-html/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#line.775) like this:

```
new DateTime().withFields(new LocalDate(2000,1,1))
```

This will set all date time fields of the `DateTime` to those that are contained in the `LocalDate` - year, month and day in this case. This will work with any `ReadablePartial` implementation like `YearMonth` for example.